# Implementing case by case type level functions in Scala

Tags: scala, metaprogramming, typeclass, scala-2.10, scala-macros

I would like to implement something, probably a macro, to implement something like

```
Int --> java.lang.Integer
Float --> java.lang.Float
```

so that I can implement something like

```
def box[X <: AnyVal : Numeric](x: X) : Boxed[X] = ...
```

that would cause `Boxed[Int]` to become `java.lang.Integer`, when instantiated.
I am not too concerned with the specific syntax or method of implementation
so long as I can write generic methods and classes that can perform ad hoc mappings on types
like above.
I know that the Scala library already has implicits like int2Integer for boxing and unboxing,
but I need to explicitly map types in a way that the compiler can typecheck.
This is mainly for implementing a typeclass whose instances have a type member that depends on the type parameters but in a non parametric way.
Currently I am defining this type member explicitly in each instance of the typeclass,
instead of computing it from the type parameters, but that adds boilerplate to all the instances

### EDIT

The above function is just an illustration. Really I am writing type class where I need to say something like:

```
trait Mapping[T, U] {
   type MapBase = java.util.Map[Box[T], Box[U]]
   type MapType <: MapBase
   def create : MapType
   ...
}
```

Where Box[T] behaves as described above. This is intended to interface with specialized Java collection libraries like FastUtil & Trove. Instances of the type class would instantiate `MapType` to specialized classes, so that

implicit object LongIntMapping extends Mapping[Long, Int] {
      type MapType = Int2LongOpenHashMap
      def create : MapType = ...
   }

should automatically get `MapBase = Map[java.lang.Long, Java.lang.Integer]` since that is what the interface that FastUtil `Int2LongOpenHashMap` implements even though it stores unboxed primitives. This is the general pattern in FastUtil: collections of native types implement Java collection interfaces for the corresponding boxed types and that is the concept I am trying to implement systematically. This of course still requires a typeclass instance for each FastUtil collection I want to use. I am also [looking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19076321/splicing-together-symbols-with-scala-macros) into macros to solve/reduce this problem. Mybe macros even avoid the need for typeclasses, but is for production code and macros being experimental ...

Comment: Why not just `x.asInstanceOf[AnyRef]`, that does the boxing automatically?

Comment: The boxing function was just a simplified example to illustrate the idea. I am really writing some typeclasses that interact with java code, and I need the type level mapping for things to type check and implicit lookup to work

Comment: You may want to look into shapeless (https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/wiki/Feature-overview:-shapeless-2.0.0)